# Prove that the following languages are equivalent

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to prove that the following languages are equivalent using induction:

P ::= ε | id | ( P )

and

S ::= ε | id | ( R

R ::= ) | S )

Need to prove that:

L(P) = L(S)

how can I do it?

I was able to prove that L(S) contains L(P), but I can't prove the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

To produce a proof by induction, we must state the claim, show it is true in the base cases, state the hypothesis and then show that the claim holds for the cases of the next size.

Our claim can be "L(P) and L(S) contain the same strings of length n for all natural n".

Our base cases can be the few smallest strings in both languages: L(P) and L(S) both contain the empty string, the only string of zero length; so the claim holds for the case n = 0. Both L(P) and L(S) contain id, the only string in the language of length two (assuming i and d are different symbols; if id is one symbol, then these strings have length one). Thus, the claim holds up to n = 2 (or n = 1, depending).

We can use strong induction, rather than plain induction, as follows: L(P) and L(S) contain all the same strings of length up to k.

Now, we must show that for strings of the next highest length, any string contained in one language is contained in the other, and vice versa.

1. Let w be a string of the next-higher length in L(P). The first production used to derive w must have been P ::= (P) since |w| > 2 (or |w| > 1) and we already covered smaller cases. Then w = (w') where w' is a string in L(P) and |w'| < |w|. But w was of the next length greater than k in L(P), so w' must have length less than or equal to k. But then, w' must be in both L(P) and L(S) by the induction hypothesis. Thus, the derivation S ::= (R ::= (S) ::= (w') is valid and produces w. So, w is in L(S).
2. Let w be a string of the next-higher length in L(S). The first production used to derive w must be S ::= (R, and the next production must have been either R ::= ) or R ::= S). Let us consider these cases separately.

   - if the second production was R ::= ), then w = S ::= (R ::= (), which we can verify is in both languages (or we can simply rely on the induction hypothesis).
   - if the second production was R ::= S), then w = S ::= (R ::= (S), so w is of the form (w') where |w'| < |w|. Since w is of the next higher length greater than k, w' has length less than or equal to k and is generated by the grammar for P.